# Spring Security CAS Client login through URL

Tags: security, spring, cas

Is there a way to be authenticated in a Spring Security application(with Spring MVC) that uses CAS client by only passing credentials through url? I have a working Spring MVC application that uses Spring Security and CAS client with a form-based login, A new requirement is to authenticate some users coming through a special URL where username and a hash key is passed to the application, and such users should also be able to view pages restricted with CAS as normal authenticated users who logged in through CAS form. May I need to request a valid CAS ticket from CAS server or any other alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do something similar to this using the REST client.

https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/RESTful+API

Once you've got a username/password it's trivial to gather a service ticket and then validate it.  Note that this completely changes the security model though, CAS is designed around transparently authenticating, using this method makes it quite explicit.  Also there are some security implications to be aware of as the blurb at the top of that page mentions.

Comment: I am currently trying to integrate it with a Spring MVC 3 application, and code sample given in https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/RESTful+API doesn't work for me because CAS server is returning no response with 401 status code. Do I  need to make some configuration changes to CAS server? If not are there any good articles to achieve this with Spring 3 or Spring Security ?

Comment: I just used the sample code on that page.  Do you have the restlet integration configured?